# How to keep a node lambda running locally

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, docker-compose, local

I've got an aws lambda running without problems. However, I have the need to run the function locally and would like to know what the best approach would be. It has to run within `docker` using `docker-compose`.

My first approach was using `localstack`, but it turned out to be rather slow. `docker-lambda` doesn't seem to be an option either as that will just run the function once, while I need a container running so the handler can be ran at any time.

My idea now is to write a simple server to accept "invokes" and execute the actual handler. Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Why do you need it to run locally?

Comment: The lambda needs to access a resource that also runs locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the environment variable `LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker-reuse` then it will reuse the lambda container for subsequent invocations and significantly speed it up (the first invocation when it spins up will still be slow, though).

The problem is that by default it spins up and shuts down the lambda on every invocation which is pretty slow.

The only issue with this solution is if you want hot reloading of your lambda code it won't automatically reload the container.